# Stacking one column while duplicating other column in Excel or Stata

Tags: excel, stata, vba

I am working on a huge dataset which is in an Excel file. The data has daily stock returns of 380 companies from 2016 to 2000. Each company has about 3800 observations. The first column has dates in Excel format that are in descending order. The successive columns have returns of companies that correspond to the dates.

I have to import that dataset to Stata for panel data analysis and unfortunately the above arrangement does not help in that. So I have to rearrange the data either in Stata or in Excel and I can't seem to do that automatically.

Rearrangement:

1. I am looking to sort all the data into just three columns only. The first column will have the company names stacked below each other.
2. The second column has the dates that duplicate itself whenever a new company starts.
3. The third column should have returns of all the companies stacked below each other.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inajq.png)

It is like converting the data into long form in Stata. I am not sure if Excel will able to handle it since each company will have 3800 rows and there are 380 companies.

In Excel, I developed Macro to stack the columns of returns but could not not make the dates column and company names move along with it.
In Stata, I tired reshape command but it gives mismatch error. Stack command let me stack the returns but it drops all the other information. I am new to Stata so I don't know how to approach this problem through developing a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give any indication of what code you actually tried in Stata: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on what makes a good question.

On the face of it your problem is soluble in Stata by something like

```
reshape long Company, i(Date) 
rename (Company _j) (Return Company)
```

Comment: Yes sir, i tried rehape but it gave mismatch error. I guess Stata is not taking dates from excel. It needs to be reformatted in its own format language. I am fairly new to Stata.

Comment: Same comment. Reporting that your code didn't work and giving vague guesses why not is hardly more informative than saying that your car or your television doesn't work. Do read the page on MCVE and give us a minimal data example and the exact code you tried and what  happened. If the problem is now with the date, that is a separate question.

Comment: I made it work. And my apologies to the community for not being specific. It is diffcult to be technically specific when you are new to something.

Comment: Everyone starts at the beginning, but all you are asked to do is show your code.